# Is there an iOS SDK for creating crossword puzzle games?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, sdk

We are looking to create a crossword puzzle game and I'd like to see how we can help our client reduce development time by using an iOS SDK. We are looking for the game interaction (loading words, dragging letters to board, word validation, etc)

Comment: I think the word you want is 'library' not 'SDK'

Comment: Don't make people drag letters to fill in a crossword.

Comment: I hardly think that you will need a 3rd party SDK to load words and word validation. That kind of stuff is super trivial. Even dragging views is not exactly rocket science.

Comment: Hi Everyone thank you for the comments so far. @DaveNewton what would you recommend outside of dragging like "Words with Friends"?

Comment: @ChrisMerkle "Typing." WwF has a small tile set. Crosswords have an alphabet. If you have an alphabet, you have a keyboard. If you have a keyboard, type.

Comment: What you want is way too specific to have a library. If I were to create an engine to create crosswords, I'd make it an app and release it myself, not release a framework...

Comment: Any knows How to Create Cross word and how to check the conditions etc . Any link you have please give me. vineeshtp88@gmail.com

Answer (score 1):

Look into [Cocoas2D](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/) or there is [Unity3D](http://unity3d.com/) to assist you in creating games for iOS.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for a 'Library' if what I understand is that you want an automated way of creating crossword puzzles. Unfortunately I do not believe there is any that would fit your needs.

If you are like me, create your own paper crossword puzzles and then make them on iOS.

A great book to get on how to make games for iOS would be '[Learning iOS Game Programming](http://www.amazon.ca/Learning-iOS-Game-Programming-Hands/dp/0321699424)" by Michael Daley.

I bet with the resources on that book and good logical planning you will have your game made in no time.